# why hyperref link text border(box) doesn't have uniform size under Xelatex

Tags: xetex, hyperref, pdftex, border

I found that the same code under different tex engines gives different hyperref link border(box) size, see the minimal sample code below:

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \href{http://blog.csdn.net}{CSDN的某博客}
\item \href{http://blog.csdn.net}{csdn的某博客}
\item \href{http://download.csdn.net/}{某下载}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

When I compile with Xelatex, I get such result, see image shot below:

[image: build with xelatex]

When I compile with PdfLatex, I get such result, see image shot below:

[image: build with pdflatex]

You see that the result from Xelatex is not quite good, because it has different link border(box) size, and the one from pdflatex shows quite good and uniform box size.

My question is: how to fix the issue in Xelatex? 
I'm using the Miktex latest 2.9 version.